# WC API REST can't POST data oauth 1.0

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, oauth, woocommerce

I'm creating angularjs client with WP API REST and WC API REST and i've got problem with POSTing data to orders. I get 401 error unauthorized. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
    angular.module('egonometriaApp')


.service('$order', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var order={
      payment_method: 'bacs'
    };
    function randomString(length, chars) {
      var result = '';
      for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
      return result;
    }

var consumer_key = "ck_ae3c4951e083094b8ae716c3b8b59eac4a35515b",
  httpMethod = "POST",
  url = "http://it-grafika.pl:8080/wp-json/wc/v2/orders",
  parameters = {
    oauth_consumer_key: consumer_key,
    oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp: (Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1000)).toString(),
    oauth_nonce: randomString(32, "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
  },
  consumerSecret = "cs_00af1fb1fa20bcf81d3c68dc8cfea4f3b9f261e9",
  tokenSecret = "",
  encodedSignature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret,
    {encodeSignature: true});
console.log(encodedSignature);
parameters['oauth_signature'] = encodedSignature;
console.log(parameters);
this.postOrder = function () {
  var config = {
    method: httpMethod,
    url: url,
    headers: {
      authorization: 'OAuth '+ 'oauth_consumer_key="'+parameters['oauth_consumer_key']+'",oauth_signature_method="'+parameters['oauth_signature_method']+
      '",oauth_timestamp="'+parameters['oauth_timestamp']+'",oauth_nonce="'+parameters['oauth_nonce']+'",oauth_version="1.0"'+',oauth_signature="'+parameters['oauth_signature']+'"',
      "Content-Type": 'Content-Type: application/json'
    }

    // data: order
  };
  $http(config)
    .then(function (status) {
      console.log(status);
    });
};
```

}])
;

It is working when i'm using Postman. No idea why authorization isn't passing thru.

This what i get in my browser 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG10r.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making cross domain request, you need to pass `withCredentials` as `true` in your config.

Your config should look like this.

```
var config = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    method: httpMethod,
    url: url,
    withCredentials : true,
    headers: {
      authorization: 'OAuth '+ 'oauth_consumer_key="'+parameters['oauth_consumer_key']+'",oauth_signature_method="'+parameters['oauth_signature_method']+
      '",oauth_timestamp="'+parameters['oauth_timestamp']+'",oauth_nonce="'+parameters['oauth_nonce']+'",oauth_version="1.0"'+',oauth_signature="'+parameters['oauth_signature']+'"',
      "Content-Type": 'Content-Type: application/json'
    }
```

Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials for more details.

Comment: This doesnt help